# En docker-compose, Error al agregar Certificado SSL a proxy reverso para consumir websocket!

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker-compose, websocket, contenedores

Implementando en [windows11](/questions/tagged/windows11), [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) y trabajando con docker-composer, estoy intentando habilitar el certificado ssl para mi setup en donde quiero habilitar que nginx como proxy reverso permita websocket seguros `wss://` y que esto sean redirigidos a mi contenedor web server, muestro a continuacionlos archivos:

Estructura del sistema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: Proxy-Server
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ${LH_CERTBOT}:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    ports:
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT:-443}:443"
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    extra_hosts:
      - "${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
      - "${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_HOST=${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      - TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY=true
      - ENABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Proxy Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=reverse-proxy"
  certbot:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: SSL-Generator
    build:
      context: ./bin/certbot
    volumes:
      - ${LH_CERTBOT}:/etc/app/update-ssl.sh
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - reverse-proxy
    networks:
      - lamp-network
  webserver:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-Web-Server
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_PHP_ENVIRONMENT}
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:rw
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ${LH_VHOSTS_DIR}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${LH_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/apache2
      - ${LH_LOG_CRON}:/var/log/cron
    environment:
      LH_WEB_MASTER: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT: ${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Web Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=webserver"
...
networks:
  lamp-network:
    name: lamp-network
    driver: bridge
```

en mi archivo Dockerfile:

```
FROM certbot/certbot

CMD chmod +x /etc/app/update-ssl.sh && ./etc/app/update-ssl.sh
```

***Lo que esperaba hacer:***

mi idea principal es montar [certbot](/questions/tagged/certbot) y compartir la interaccion entre contenedores para una vez que `certbot` se ha iniciado completamente; ejecutar la generacion de certificado utilizando el archivo `/etc/app/update-ssl.sh` y mandar a reiniciar el servicio nginx en el contenedor `reverse-proxy` para que este lea y obtenga el certificado `ssl`

***El Error que obtengo:***
pero a pesar que se armar los contenedor es el del certbot no arranca y en el log muestra este error:

> 2023-09-25 16:09:10 usage:  2023-09-25 16:09:10   certbot [SUBCOMMAND]
> [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ... 2023-09-25 16:09:10  2023-09-25
> 16:09:10 Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates.
> By default, 2023-09-25 16:09:10 it will attempt to use a webserver
> both for obtaining and installing the 2023-09-25 16:09:10 certificate.
> 2023-09-25 16:09:10 certbot: error: Unable to open config file: chmod
> +x /etc/app/update-ssl.sh && ./etc/app/update-ssl.sh. Error: No such file or directory

***Espectativa:***
Aunque los errores estan relacionados al montaje y ejecucion del archivo, el solucionarlo no garantiza que mi script `/etc/app/update-ssl.sh` haga lo que espero:

Archivo `/etc/app/update-ssl.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Define variables
WEB_ROOT="${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}"

# Run Certbot to obtain the SSL certificate
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path="$WEB_ROOT" --email "${LH_WEB_MASTER}" --agree-tos -d "${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}" -d "${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}"

# Check if the certificate was obtained successfully
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Certificate obtained successfully. Restarting Nginx in the reverse-proxy container..."
  # Restart Nginx in the reverse-proxy container using Docker
  docker exec -it reverse-proxy service nginx restart
else
  echo "Certificate acquisition failed."
fi

# Start Certbot's renewal process in the background
certbot renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade &
# Keep the container running
exec "$@"
```

en pocas palabras nisiquiera se si lo que estoy haciendo funcionara o de entrada ya estoy haciendo mal la implementacion del certificado SSL

***Preguntas:***

1. <del>Es correcto en enfoque?</del>
2. <del>Como soluciono el error de montar el archivo `.sh` para ejecutarlo desde `CMD` (cuando el contenedor se pone en marcha).</del>
3. <del>Aunque aun no he probado el archivo script `/etc/app/update-ssl.sh` me gustaria, no me queda claro si cumplira con la intencion de hacer el reinicio del servicio nginx en un contenedor separado.</del>

***Objetivo Final:***
Habilitar websocket en un Entorno LAMP+proxy-reverso en docker, para el desarrollo de subsistemas de: chat, notificaciones y saldo de inventarios de producto en tiempo real.

***Contexto:***
Antes de hacer esta publicacion he intentado agotar mi capacidad investigativa y las publicaciones de este sitio y del sitio en ingles, incluso otros sitios no estan enfocados a cubrir el escenario que yo presento por lo tanto, el avance que tengo es un hibrido de varios setup.

***--UPDATE--***

he estado investigando sobre el tema y del resultado he logrado al parecer instalar el certificado por lo menos no he perdido acceso via el puerto 80, pero ahora me arroja un error 500, el cual no logro encontrar en los logs de errores, para llegar a este punto he actualizado el setup, el codigo de configuracion del entorno en `docker-compose.yaml` ya no es el mismo:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: Proxy-Server
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    ports:
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT:-443}:443"
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    environment:
      - TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY=true
      - ENABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    privileged: true

  nginx-ssl:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: SSL-Generator
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: Proxy-Server
      DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
    depends_on:
      - reverse-proxy
    networks:
      - lamp-network
  webserver:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-Web-Server
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_PHP_ENVIRONMENT}
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:rw
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ${LH_VHOSTS_DIR}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${LH_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/apache2
      - ${LH_LOG_CRON}:/var/log/cron
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LH_WEB_MASTER: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
      LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT: ${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Web Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=webserver"
...
  phpmyadmin:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: ${LH_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
      MEMORY_LIMIT: ${LH_MEMORY_LIMIT}
    volumes:
      - /sessions
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=phpMyAdmin"
      - "lh2.setup.role=phpmyadmin"
...
volumes:
  vhost:
  html:
  certs:
  acme:
  conf:
  dhparam:
networks:
  lamp-network:
    name: lamp-network
    driver: bridge
```

Archivo Virtual host que se monta en mi webserver:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
    DocumentRoot ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
    ServerName ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
    ServerAlias *.${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
    <Directory ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

En cuanto phpMyAdmin tengo el mismo error, pero no he creado ningun virtual host, solo se hace la instalacion directa de la imagen.

## Contexto Actual:

Lo que estoy intentando es poder anclar la comunicación entre en proxy-reverso y el contenedor webserver y phpmyamin es vía intranet de docker... implementando `VIRTUAL_HOST` lo que sí creo es que el contendor que corre apache, a pesar de tener el puerto 443 abierto el apache no está configurado para hacer nada con él,  he agregar la configuración de ese virtual host a este post previamente, recordar que todo esto lo estoy haciendo desde el archivo `YAML`, estoy buscando la forma de evitar la terminal... por cuestiones de automatización en la instalación, ahora todo esto gira en torno al consumo de websocket; no veo la forma de anclar el certificado ssl tanto al proxy como al web server, pensaba que la idea era consumir el ssl solo con el proxy y que este se comunicara únicamente por el puerto 80 para consumir los contenedores ... pero mi error ahora  que estoy pagando es querer que también se consuma el puerto 443 del contenedor web server por ende también el de phpmyadmin ... y crear la compatibilidad con un futuro ambiente de producción si es que lo estén implementando.

Comment: si entiendo bien nginx va por frente a apache como proxypass/proxyreverse y es apache el que enlaza con php ( via mod php ) ?. si es así el tema de puerto 80 funcionando y error 500 en el puerto 443  puede deberse a que el servicio apache no pudo levantar en esa interfaz/puerto ( si lo hace en el 80, el 443 debe estar tomado por nginx )

Comment: lo primero que has mencionado si es asi... lo segundo que as mencionado no lo es ...

Comment: la comunicacion entre en proxy-reverso y el contenedor apache es via intranet de docker... implementando virtual host.

Comment: @aloMalbarez lo que si creo que tiene razon es que el contendor que corre apache, a pesar de tener el puerto 443 abierto el apache no esta configurado para hacer nada con el, voy a agregar la configuracion de ese virtual host.

Comment: @aloMalbarez solo para tambien recordarte que todo esto lo estoy haciendo desde el archivo YML, estoy buscando la forma de evitar la terminal... por cuestiones de automatizacion en la instalacion.

Comment: ahora todo esto gira entorno al consumo de websocket; no veo la forma de anclar el certificado ssl tanto al proxy como al web server, pensaba que la idea era consumir el ssl solo con el proxy y que este se comunicara unicamente por el puerto 80 para consumir los contenedores ...

Comment: mi error ahora es querer que tambien se consuma el puerto 443 del contenedor web server ... y crear la compatibilidad con un futuro ambiente de produccion que lo este usando.

Comment: 1/ si, ahi vi que son dos contenedores diferentes, si fuera todo en el mismo podes bindear apache a una interfaz interna/local( ip ) y nginx a la interfaz externa. con 2 contenedores cada uno esta en su lugar. el tema certificados depende un poco de la aplicación ( apache+php ) si la app levanta sin ssl es cuestion de ponerla en el puerto 80 y que solo responda al proxy, el proxy es el q crea y mantiene el "tunel".

Comment: @aloMalbarez el problema con eso que sugieres es que el proyecto que estoy trabajando posiblemente sea subido a un hosting web, obviamente el hosting  va a correr **sin docker y con un ssl** ... entonces cuando usen websocket y lo implementen con `wss;//` no va a funcionar por que el proyecto en local estaria desarrollado con el puerto **80**, esto es mi percepcion ...

Comment: 2/ para tener los 2 en ssl ( proxy y app ) el proxy debe poder confiar en el app, es decir q hay que agregarle al cert store del proxy el certificado/chain del app ( mismo caso q cuando agregas a tu OS/browser cert store un self signed cert ) . masomenos como funciona cloudflare en modo estricto https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes/full-strict/

Comment: ya me liaste con cloudflare XD, entiendo pero no se como implementarlo XD, pensaba en algo stanalone y depender lo menos posible de la conectividad a internet XD... para el desarrollo ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148757/discussion-between-alo-malbarez-and-arcanisgk507).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era el enfoque, anteriormente di esta respuesta para editar y agregar las url y la ip al archivo host... asique me aproveche de este enfoque para también hacer otras tareas de forma programática mediante scripting en poweshell, en teoría esto sería un workaround pero es lo más automático y sencillo a tener que pegarse de la terminal y escribir los comando uno a uno para gestionar los contendores que y características que se requieren.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77246850/22473069

Ahora lo que que incorpore fue validar la existencia o hacer la instalacion de `chocolately`, luego evaluar la existencia o hacer la instalacion de `mkcert`

ya que son dependecias, pueden verificar esto en la [documentacion](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert)

Bueno aqui todo va en el script de ps:

```
function Get-Security {
    [Console]::Clear()
    Get-TittleScreen
    Write-Host "`n Would you like to enable HTTPS and WSS protocols via SSL (default: No)."  -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host " Note: if yes, this will open port: 443; otherwise only port 80 would work."
    Write-Host "`n => 1. No. (press any Key)."
    Write-Host " => 2. Yes (press Y or 2)."
    Get-AddCyanLine; $choice = Read-Host " Choose option 1 or 2 (Press any key for default: 1/No)"
    if ($choice -eq "2" -or $choice -eq "Y" -or $choice -eq "y") {
        return $true
    } else {
        return $false
    }
}

function Get-DefaultOrCustom {
    [Console]::Clear()
    Get-TittleScreen
    Write-Host "`n Configure custom URLs to use locally."  -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host " Note: At this point you will decide if you want to use custom URLs or the ones that Stack uses by default."
    Write-Host "`n => 1. Use the default url [ lh-stack.dock | pma.lh-stack.dock ]."
    Write-Host " => 2. Indicate the URLs you want to Implement."
    Get-AddCyanLine
    $choice = Read-Host " Choose option 1 or 2 (Press any key for default: 1)"
    if ($choice -eq "2") {
        return $false
    } else {
        return $true
    }
}

function Get-Url {
    param (
        [string]$texto
    )
    [Console]::Clear()
    Get-TittleScreen
    Write-Host "`n Indicate here a URL to use."
    Write-Host " Note: Try to make your url belong to a wildcard (example.dock, pma.example.dock)"
    Write-Host " $texto"
    Get-AddCyanLine
    Write-Host " ==> : " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "Red"
    return Read-Host
}

function Get-UrlConfirm {
    param (
        [string]$main_url,
        [string]$pma_url
    )
    [Console]::Clear()
    Get-TittleScreen
    Write-Host "`n Confirmation URL."  -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host " You have requested the configuration of custom URLs:"
    Write-Host "`n Main Url: $main_url" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    Write-Host " PhpMyAdmin: $pma_url" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    Write-Host "`n => press [Y]es or any key to confirm and continue."
    Write-Host " => press [N]o to set it again."
    Get-AddCyanLine
    Write-Host " ==>" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "Red"
    $choice = Read-Host
    if ($choice -eq "N") {
        return $true
    } else {
        return $false
    }
}

function Get-SslCerts {
    param (
        [string]$main_url,
        [string]$pma_url
    )
    [Console]::Clear()
    Get-TittleScreen
    Write-Host "`n SSL certificates are required for this instance."  -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Get-AddTask; Write-Host "Generating Certificates with mkcert..."
    $certPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/docker/config/ssl/"
    mkcert -cert-file "$certPath$main_url.crt" -key-file "$certPath$main_url.key" "$main_url" "*.$main_url" "$pma_url" "*.$pma_url" >> run.log 2>&1
    Get-EndTask; Write-Host "SSL Certificates Generated!!!!!!"
    Get-AddCyanLine
    Get-Pause
}

#=========================================#
# Environment Preparation

[Console]::Clear()
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "|| Environment Installer and Setup ||"
$scriptDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Set-Location -Path $scriptDirectory

#=========================================#
# Execution

Get-Administrator
$summaryPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/summary.txt"
Start-Transcript -Path $summaryPath  >> run.log 2>&1
$security = Get-Security
Install-Prerequisite -security $security
if (Get-DefaultOrCustom -eq $true) {
    $main_url = "lh-stack.dock"
    $pma_url = "pma.lh-stack.dock"
} else {
    $confirm = $true
    while ($confirm) {
        $main_url = Get-Url -texto "Indicate what will be the Local Url of your Web Server"
        $pma_url = Get-Url -texto "Indicate what the Local Url will be for phpMyAdmin"
        $confirm = Get-UrlConfirm -main_url $main_url -pma_url $pma_url
    }
}

if($security){
    $protocol="https://"
    Get-SslCerts -main_url $main_url -pma_url $pma_url
} else {
    $protocol="http://"
}
```

Quien hace la magia son los comandos:

```
choco install mkcert >> run.log 2>&1
```

y

```
mkcert -install >> run.log 2>&1
```

y

```
mkcert -cert-file "$certPath$main_url.crt" -key-file "$certPath$main_url.key" "$main_url" "*.$main_url" "$pma_url" "*.$pma_url" >> run.log 2>&1
```

con esto queda montado el ssl e incluso registrado en el local storage:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]